# Why is my docker container not saving files i incorporate into it?

Tags: docker, containers

I am testing to see if my commit changes are working for my container. So I create a test file, that just contains text and then I commmit it, then push it to my repository(tagged as latest). Whenever I re-download via docker pull myrepository name. It no longer contains the text file I created as a test.

How can I manipulate it so that the changes I actually make within the container will remain there after I commit, push, and pull back down?

```
docker pull twsee/atsci405
docker run -it twsee/atsci405 /bin/bash
```

create file within the main directory of /bin/bash/

exit the container

```
docker commit 6e667bab0bb967656e81d343d33ffe7dfae35afb868b137ea425e5dbe3533b0c twsee/atsci405:latest
docker push twsee/atsci405:latest
```

ignore the miss matched container IDs

Comment: You need to `commit` the changes inside the docker container: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: Hello your assumptions are correct, so you probably missed some step. Could you please post the command sequence you used?

Comment: @Hackerman  Oh this needs to be done BEFORE I exit the container while its running?

Comment: @twseewx, yes, exactly :)

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez Inside the container, vi testfiel -> insert text. save and exit. exit the container. docker commit changing the name adding tag of latest to it. then docker pushing to my repository. remove container and image. docker pull the newly saved image from my repository. nothing new has been commited.

Comment: @Hackerman i guess my issue is that when i exit the container the container is no longer running. i access it via 

docker run -it container name /bin/bash/ 

so once I exit i guess it stops the container and doesn't allow the commits to be applied?

Comment: @twseewx yes your pseudo code looks good so please paste the commands in your question body

Comment: @twseewx the way is to commit when the container is not running

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez i have updated the body of my question.

Comment: Do you have a VOLUME tag in your Dockerfile to /bin/bash ?

Comment: You may use `Dockerfile` as well. What test you did to confirm that the file / directory is not created after commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your flow. I saw a comment above saying you need to commit a 'running' container. That's not correct. See the following:

```
$ docker run -it alpine:3.3 sh
# touch testfile
# ls
bin     home   ... testfile ...
# exit
$ docker commit $(docker ps -aql) johnharris85/test-commit:latest
$ docker push johnharris85/test-commit:latest
$ docker rmi johnharris85/test-commit:latest
$ docker run -it johnharris85/test-commit:latest sh
# ls
bin     home   ... testfile ...
```

You see different results? Can you post your parent image Dockerfile? Maybe some issue with volumes?

Answer (score 0):

Due to placing the file within the /bin/bash location it removed it from the image when I pushed it. However I placed several within each directory that followed /bin/bash and each test file remained within the image the next pull I did.